# How can I smoothly detect the welding joint using OpenCV-Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-learn

I have tried to detect the welding joint (bead) using the codes attached below in the last part of this question. I aim to draw a contour on the joint as shown in the third image but my results are poor and don't look similar to the expected results. here is the summary of what I did but the codes are well clear:
1. Reading the image `.jpg` format
2. Image blurring
3. Thresholding
4. Morphological operations
5. Creating mask
6. Finding contour

But the results are not promising, how can I get out from here

````
img_new = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur_image = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_new,5,21,21)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur_image,255,
                               cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                               cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,15,3)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),dtype='uint8')
thresh_dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations = 1)
num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh_dilated, connectivity=4)
sizes = stats[1:,-1]
min_size = 5000
num_labels = num_labels -1
img2 = np.zeros((labels.shape))
for i in range(0,num_labels):
    if sizes[i]>=min_size:
        img2[labels==i+1]=255
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img2,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(closing,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel)
result = opening.copy()
new_result = result.astype(dtype=np.uint8)

black = np.full((new_result.shape[0],new_result.shape[1],3),(0,0,0),np.uint8)
black1 = cv2.ellipse(black,(700,750),(300,140),0,0,360,(255,255,255),-1)
grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(black1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,b_mask = cv2.threshold(grayscale,127,255,0)
img_result = cv2.bitwise_and(new_result,b_mask)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_result, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('result',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read any [papers](https://www.google.com/search?q=image+processing+welding&oq=image+processing+welding)?

Is this for automatic processing of many welding joints on an assembly line? Does this have to work for many other similiar images? It does not make sense to fine tune an algorithm for a single picture in that case.

If yes, than you need to use more images to create the algorithm, maybe use a different light setup, maybe images taken with an IR camera right after the welding to get a "hot" mask. Or use light from left and right sight separately to combine two images for a single mark.

Another thing that would be very helpful is to get a "before" image from the parts. without the welding joint. In that case it could get easy. You would just create the difference between the images, do some filtering to remove the welding beads and the reddish layer.

Edit 1:

Another thing I forgot to mention is please look at the RGB layers separately. This is something that you should always try early on. Often there is something useful to see, e.g. in your case it could be that the blue layer might be interesting. Please add the layers to your question.

Comment: Yes. It has to work with many welding joints (16 images). What you are saying is exactly true because when I tried to smooth and detect one image the results were not like the one from the first image.

I was thinking if anyone has an idea that can help me to automate the above algorithm such that it can correctly or approximately detect joints of the welding for the rest of the images

Comment: Added some more info (about RGB).

Comment: Just one general thing: image processing like that is usually trial and error. There are some concepts to apply, but you often have to do a lot of fine tuning to really fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution..... do you mean that you need more images (RGB) to be uploaded?

Comment: That would make it possible for us to contribute. But for sure you should look at them. I have a feeling that the blue layer might be interesting.

Comment: Sure. I have such a feeling is it possible to send you the images by email because in StackOverflow is possible to attach one file at once and not many files at per

Comment: Not all files. For the image you posted above, extract RBG and post only these three images in your question.

Comment: Is it possible to attach an image to the comments? Or am I am supposed to edit the question again? Once more: The initial format was `RGB` do you want me to swap the G, B channel to B, G channel, and post the RBG images only?

Comment: Not its not possible to attach to the comments. Please edit the question and add the images there.

Comment: Sorry for a delay I have edited the question by adding three more images. Thanks

Comment: Not more images, but the RGB layers separately as one image each.

Comment: see bottom https://webstyleguide.com/wsg2/graphics/displays.html

Comment: or hhttps://datacarpentry.org/image-processing/03-skimage-images/

Comment: or http://gameautomators.com/book/ImageProcessing/2-color.html

Comment: The idea is that one of the layers might hold better information to create a maks.